# Java Cannot convert from Object to Integer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My saldoservidor entity has a one to one association with servidor. I created this table to hold the records of the employee id and the amount of money they can spend (which is 30% of their salary).

So I tried creating a service class for that, but I'm stuck... I thought about saving the servidor entity and then getting and setting the respective fields for saldoservidor. But since idservidor is an integer, how am I going to set it on saldoservidor?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.SaldoServidor;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity.Servidor;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.repositories.SaldoServidorRepository;
import com.camaratapira.syspharma.repositories.ServidorRepository;

@Service
public class ServidorService {
    
    @Autowired
    ServidorRepository servidorRepository;  
    @Autowired
    SaldoServidorRepository saldoServidorRepository;

    public void addServidor(Servidor servidor) {
        
        SaldoServidor sal = new SaldoServidor();
        
        servidorRepository.save(servidor);
        
        double salario = servidor.getSalario();
        double saldo = (salario * 30 / 100);
        
        sal.setIdsaldo(sal.getIdsaldo());
        sal.setServidor(servidor); // how can I set this property?
        sal.setSaldo(saldo);
        saldoServidorRepository.save(sal);
                
    }   
}
```

Servidor entity

```
package com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "servidor")
public class Servidor {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "idservidor")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // outras estratégias precisam de tabelas específicas no Banco de dados
    private Integer idservidor;
    
    @Column(name = "nomeservidor")
    private String nomeservidor;
    
    @Column(name = "cpf")
    private String cpf;
    
    @Column(name = "rg")
    private String rg;
    
    @Column(name = "salario")
    private double salario;

    @Column(name = "ativo")
    private boolean ativo;
        
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idfuncao")
    private Funcao funcao; // necessário fazer os métodos getters e setters dessas funções para poderem retornar as 
    // chaves estrangeiras quando você fizer uma requisição GET, caso contrário, o sistema não vai saber onde procurar.

    public Integer getIdservidor() {
        return idservidor;
    }
    
    public Servidor() {}
    
    public Servidor(Integer idservidor, String nomeservidor, String cpf, String rg, double salario, boolean ativo,
            Funcao funcao) {
        super();
        this.idservidor = idservidor;
        this.nomeservidor = nomeservidor;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.rg = rg;
        this.salario = salario;
        this.ativo = ativo;
        this.funcao = funcao;
    }

    public void setIdservidor(Integer idservidor) {
        this.idservidor = idservidor;
    }

    public String getNomeservidor() {
        return nomeservidor;
    }

    public void setNomeservidor(String nomeservidor) {
        this.nomeservidor = nomeservidor;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }

    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }


    public Funcao getFuncao() {
        return funcao;
    }

    public void setFuncao(Funcao funcao) {
        this.funcao = funcao;
    }
    
}
```

SaldoServidor entity

```
package com.camaratapira.syspharma.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "saldoservidor")
public class SaldoServidor {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idsaldo;
    @Column(name = "saldo")
    private double saldo;
    
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Servidor.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "matricula", referencedColumnName = "idservidor")
    private Servidor matricula;

    public int getIdsaldo() {
        return idsaldo;
    }
    
    public SaldoServidor() {}

    public SaldoServidor(int idsaldo, double saldo, Servidor matricula) {
        super();
        this.idsaldo = idsaldo;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public void setIdsaldo(int idsaldo) {
        this.idsaldo = idsaldo;
    }

    
    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public Servidor getServidor() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setServidor(Servidor matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    
}
```

Matricula on the saldoservidor table is a foreign key referencing idservidor on the servidor table.

[image: servidor table]

[image: saldoservidor table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository method save() has a return value and it will be the saved entity, complete with the id. You can use it in the setter:

```
servidor = servidorRepository.save(servidor);
sal.setServidor(servidor);
```